# How support schemas using Mongoskin.

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoskin, soajs

Is there a way to implement Schemas in Mongoskin using SOAjs?

I want to populate a document with its reference ObjectID.

Answer (score 1):

SOAJS currently integrates only with mongoskin driver. Unlike mangoose, mongoskin doesn't enforce any strict schema to handle DB operations which makes it more flexible.

SOAJS enforces all input schemas to be handled at the [IMFV](http://www.soajs.org/#/documentation/core/imfv) layer.
you may want to look into that.